# How to put my .htaccess in my virtualhost?

Tags: apache

I would like to know if it's possible to put .htaccess instructions directly in my virtualhost.

My .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I try on my virtualhost (some instructions are deliberately deleted for this topic) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain.dev
    ServerAlias www.domain.dev

    <Directory /www/htdocs/domain/html/>

            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All

    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

But my browser responds :

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Comment: so look at the sever's error log for details about why/how the request was bad.

Comment: The only log's message when I load my page: (error.log of apache) [Sat Feb 22 22:49:48 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 192.168.1.66] Zlib: Compressed 302 to 222 : URL /index/index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work with :

```
<Directory /www/htdocs/domain/html/>

    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

</Directory>
```